# Flaticon smooth scaling effect on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to give my flat icons a nice smooth scale effect on hover. I have tried this but that doesn't work (the zoom works, but no smooth effect). Any idea what the issue is?

Thanks,

```
.flaticon-city:before {
font-size: 64px !important;
margin-left: 0px !important;
color: #00ACDE;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.flaticon-city:hover {
    transform:scale(1.3);
}
```

and this doesn't work either:

```
.flaticon-city:before {
font-size: 64px !important;
margin-left: 0px !important;
color: #00ACDE;
}

.flaticon-city:hover {
    transform:scale(1.3);
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;

}
```

Comment: Could you please provide us some working Fiddle for your problem?

Comment: there's 2 errors on your code: **1**-your `:before` have no `content:`; **2**-your transitions must be on the main element, not on `:before`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried this but that doesn't work (the zoom works, but no smooth effect). Any idea what the issue is?

The issue is simply that you specified `transition` for `.flaticon-city:before`, but apply the `transform` on `.flaticon-city:hover`.

---

Edit:

It “doesn’t work” in your example, because you have a problem with specificity:

```
#page-content #services .service i {
    /* … */
    transition: color .4s ease;
}
.flaticon-city:hover {
    transform: scale(1.3);
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

The first rule as higher specificity than the second one, but they both apply to the same `i` element that holds your icon – and therefor, you have now specified `color` as transition property only (because you have *overwritten* the transition), so changing the `transform` is not transitioned any more.

Just combine the two transitions into one:

```
#page-content #services .service i {
    transition: transform 2s ease-in-out, color .4s ease;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I had tried this as well but without success:
.flaticon-city:hover {
    transform:scale(1.3);
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;

}

Comment: Specify the transition for `.flaticon-city`

Comment: Argh, that doesn't work. I have added a link to my question if you have time to take a look.